How to request access token for Microsoft Graph API in .NET Core application?
I'm trying to create a quick, simple Teams channel demo app, but am stuck trying to figure out the Graph API. I'm able to test the available endpoints through the Graph Explorer in the browser. I have a subscription to use the endpoints, and just have to be logged in to use the Explorer.
When requesting an access token in a .NET Core application, how do I set up that request? I've been trying to look through the documentation to understand, but it isn't clear. I need a Client ID, Client Secret, a defined Scope, among other things.
What I don't understand:
How the Client ID and secret are generated through app registration in Entra, as I'm not sure how I'd be registering my small test app to generate those. Also, in what way is the Scope modified from the default? Lastly, I need to specify my Microsoft Teams account (credentials) in the API call so it can query endpoints for data specific to my account; the channels I'm part of, for example. How is this set up in the .NET Core code?

.NET Core. Sorry, been a long day. I'll edit it in title.

After inside the generated app , you could find the  Client ID and inside the secret tab you could re-generated the secret , the secret could only be seen when new generated. The graph api contains the request body which you could check with, just follow the document to send the right body and then it will work.

@BrandoZhang How do I link the registered app to my .NET core app? Where does my Teams username and password get referred in the code?

No need to get the username and password inside the application, when you are using this application, it will firstly redirect to the Azure AD login page, after user typed in the username and password, it will generated the access token, by using this access token, you could call graph api to send the message to the teams.

@BrandoZhang But how do I call the API endpoint to generate the token? They have an endpoint for it, but I don't know how to get it working. I'm having trouble with the instructions they provided.

After you login in you could follow this article to use authorizationHeaderProvider get the  access token .
